# Center a span which includes text in a container div when in overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a container div that is 40px x 40px. In it there is an anchor which includes an img that has the same dimensions as the container, and below the img, a span containing a line of text. I'm looking to center the text horizontally with the img. I've tried setting container to tex-align: center, toying with the position elements, and setting the margins to auto. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="crsContainer">
    <a class="crsIcon" onclick="return false">
        <img id="" src="'.$crsRow['iconURL'].'"/>
    </a>
    <span class="crsTitle">'.$crsRow['courseTitle'].'</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.crsContainer{
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   position: absolute;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;

 }

 .crsIcon{
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;

 }

 .crsTitle{
     position: relative;
     top: 5px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     margin: 0 auto;
     color: #3d3d3d;
     text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: Could you please provide us a fiddle or post your rendered HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a CSS transform to dra the span back 50% of it's own width.

```css
.crsContainer {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; /* for demo purposes */
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.crsIcon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.crsTitle {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="crsContainer">
    <a class="crsIcon" onclick="return false">
        <img id="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-40-40-4.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <span class="crsTitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, amet.</span>
</div>
```